# After soaking beans for 4 hours shall I peel the separated peelings off or cook them along with the beans?

Tags: beans

I soaked white beans for 4 hours, shall I pull the peelings off that are separating from the beans, or cook the peeling as well?

Comment: what kind of beans, and what are you trying to make? Most of the time you'd leave the skins on the beans, but for some specific purposes you might remove them (a recipe would probably say).

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Our answerers will need more information to actually help you.  See Rdd's question above.

Comment: Did you start with dried beans? 4 hours is a short time for skins to start peeling off.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can leave the skins in - but you don't have to.

The only reasons to pick them out would be if you don't like the appearance, or if the dish leads to loose skins that you find unpleasant.

I soak overnight before slow-cooking, and don't deliberately remove skins, but some come off in rinsing and are left behind.  At the start of cooking, many beans still have their skins on, which then go on to fall off as they're cooked.  This means that to avoid loose skins in the finished dish you're likely to have to put some effort in to removing them all